# st_contains in athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

the below code should return true but returns false. I tested in google maps and point lies in the polygon. I am not sure what is the issue here. I am running this code in Athena

```
select 
st_contains (st_polygon( 'POLYGON((54.8163815 24.9474831),
(54.9310513 24.8914383),
(55.0514856 24.8349286),
(55.1170345 24.9527804),
(55.1686306 25.0937019),
(55.3738202 25.1844963),
(55.3676957 25.3050482),
(55.2592057 25.3944044),
(54.8163815 24.9474831))'),st_point(55.163485,25.092776))
```

Comment: Interestingly, all the examples on [List of Supported Geospatial Functions - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/geospatial-functions-list.html) also return False. I think there is a bug somewhere. I will report the error.

Comment: Yes I did try that as well @JohnRotenstein feels strange to me

Comment: @parthasarathy have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response I obtained from the Athena team:

The root cause is the string to create the polygon is in **wrong format**. If you run this query:

```sql
select st_geometry_to_text(st_polygon('POLYGON((54.8163815 24.9474831),
(54.9310513 24.8914383),
(55.0514856 24.8349286),
(55.1170345 24.9527804),
(55.1686306 25.0937019),
(55.3738202 25.1844963),
(55.3676957 25.3050482),
(55.2592057 25.3944044),
(54.8163815 24.9474831))'));
```

then the error message states: `corrupted geometry`

The correct format/syntax, according to the [Well-Known Text (WKT)](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AnalyzingData/Geospatial/Spatial_Definitions/WellknownTextWKT.htm) should be:

```sql
select st_contains('POLYGON(
(54.8163815 24.9474831,
54.9310513 24.8914383,
55.0514856 24.8349286,
55.1170345 24.9527804,
55.1686306 25.0937019,
55.3738202 25.1844963,
55.3676957 25.3050482,
55.2592057 25.3944044,
54.8163815 24.9474831))',
st_point(55.163485,25.092776));
```

and it will return `true`.