# check if point intersects polygon in aws athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am trying to move MySQL code into AWS athena.

I have two tables, one with location_name and boundary(polygon) and another table with rent_location(point)

I've joined them and created a new column that specify location_name of where rent_location intersects.

Here is my query in MySQL:

```
select
  r.*, 
  l.location_name
from rent r
left join location l 
   on ST_Intersects(l.polygon,  ST_Point(ST_X(r.rent_location), ST_Y(r.rent_location)))
```

This works perfectly however when I try to do this in Aws Athena it won't work.
I've been looking at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/geospatial-functions-list.html and trying multiple ways.

rent_location, l.polygon are both binary data type.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

What I've tried:

1. From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/geospatial-example-queries.html I've check that ST_X(r.rent_location) converts binary to decimal however it does not work.

In Athena it didn't recognize lat,lng unless you gave it an alias of lat lng therefore I've done:

```
WITH rent as(
    select ST_X(rent_location) as lng
         , ST_Y(rent_location) as lat
      from rent_table
)
select
  r.*, 
  l.location_name
from rent r
left join location l 
   on ST_Intersects(l.polygon,  Point(ST_X(r.rent_location), ST_Y(r.rent_location)))
```

however still doesn't work. I've tried both ST_INTERSECT and ST_Contains. The only thing different from example is that ST_X(r.rent_location) outputs decimal data type instead of double.

When I run above query I get

```
[Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: Input data format is not validated or supported
```

I think it is because of decimal datatype?

How can I change it to double datatype inside my query?

EDIT 2:
I've change datatype of ST_X(rent_location) to double by using `cast(ST_X(rent_location) as double)`

but still same GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR.

Comment: Sounds like the same bug reported in: [sql - st_contains in athena - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535666/st-contains-in-athena)

Comment: I can't even get to that stage lol

Comment: Perhaps you can show some lines of input data of the tables you use..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing datatype of polygon from binary to string fixed my problem. I've set that when creating table schema, instead of saving polygon as binary used string data type.

Comment: Can you also pos the SQL query that worked for you here so it will help others?

Comment: query in the question works perfectly, datatype of polygon needed to be a string.

Comment: I am a bit surprised and very interested to see how you passed three parameters to ST_Intersects in Athena. If you can update your answer with the query I would love to reach presto via JIRA to update the signature.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing three arguments to ST_Intersects instead of two. Refer to [ST_Intersects](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/geospatial.html) and [this](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/e7eeeedcc9751c022ffb9df648ee5442cd421c32/presto-geospatial/src/test/java/io/prestosql/plugin/geospatial/TestGeoFunctions.java#L883) for syntax which only accepts two values.

You should try this part alone and then you can use it with larger query.Also verify the data format that you are using which should matching with the example that I shared from Github.

Final thing is to run this query directly in Athena with out JDBC connection so that we can rule out the issue is not happening with Simba JDBC driver.

Comment: You are supposed to pass in 3 arguments. Trying to see (lat,lng) intersects a polygon therefore you need 3. I've edited my answer explaining how I've solved it. Thanks anyways!